# What is the minimal polynomial of $T^{-1}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

> Suppose $T$ is an invertible linear operator on a finite dimensional vector space with minimal polynomial $p_T=x^m+a_{m-1}x^{m-1}+...+a_1x+a_0$. Is it true that the minimal polynomial of $T^{-1}$ is given by $p_{T^{-1}}=x^m+\frac{1}{a_0}(a_{1}x^{m-1}+...+a_{m-1}x+1)$?

I think the answer is yes, but I could not find an online source to corroborate this (although I can find references for the the characteristic polynomial of $T^{-1}$). I also posted this as a question with my work a while back,but didn't really get the answer I was looking for:

[Minimal Polynomial of Inverse](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2305985/minimal-polynomial-of-inverse)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lemma: Given a non-constant polynomial
$$ p(x) = x^m+a_{m-1}x^{m-1}+\ldots+a_0,\qquad a_0\neq 0$$
then $\xi\neq 0$ is a root of $p(x)$ iff $\frac{1}{\xi}$ is a root of the reciprocal polynomial
$$ q(x) = a_0 x^m + a_1 x^{m-1} +\ldots + 1. $$

Proof: $p(\xi)=0$ implies $\frac{p(\xi)}{\xi^m} = q\left(\frac{1}{\xi}\right)=0$ and $\xi\to\frac{1}{\xi}$ is an involution.

If $T$ is an invertible linear operator and $p,q$ are the minimal polynomials of $T,T^{-1}$ is is not difficult to show that $\text{deg } p = \text{deg } q$ since both $\text{deg } p \leq \text{deg } q$ and $\text{deg } p \geq \text{deg } q$ have to hold. Then the claim follows from the above Lemma.

Answer (score 1):

We have

$p_T(T) = 0, \tag 1$

that is,

$\sum_0^m a_i T^i = 0, \tag 2$

with $a_m = 1$; since $T$ is invertible, $T^{-m}$ exists and we may multiply (2) through by this to get

$q(T^{-1}) = \sum_0^m a_i T^{i - m} = 0. \tag 3$

We note that $T$ nonsingular implies $a_0 \ne 0$; otherwise we would have

$T(\sum_1^m a_i T^{i - 1}) = \sum_0^m a_i T^i = 0, \tag 4$

from which, since $T^{-1}$ exists,

$\sum_1^m a_i T^{i - 1} = 0; \tag 5$

however,

$\deg (\sum_1^m a_i x^{i - 1}) = m - 1 < m = \deg p_T(x), \tag 6$

contradicting the minimality of $p_T(x)$; so $a_0 \ne 0$.

Since $a_0 \ne 0$, the leading coefficient of

$q(x) = \sum_0^m a_i x^{m - i} \tag 7$

does not vanish and $\deg q(x) = m$.

I claim that

$a_0^{-1}q(x) = \sum_0^m a_0^{-1} a_i x^{m - i} \tag 8$

is the minimal polynomial of $T^{-1}$; it is clearly monic and satisfied by $T^{-1}$.  If there were a polynomial

$r(x) = \sum_0^n r_i x^i \tag 9$

with $n = \deg r(x) < m$ such that

$r(T^{-1}) = 0, \tag {10}$

then

$T^n r(T^{-1}) = \sum_0^n r_i T^{n - i} = 0; \tag{11}$

but

$\deg \sum_0^n r_i x^{n - i} \le n < m, \tag {12}$

contradicting the minimality of $p_T(x)$; thus $p_{T^{-1}}(x) = a_0^{-1}q(x)$ is the minimal polynomial of $T^{-1}$.