# Applications of the characteristic polynomial and the inverse matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be an invertible matrix of order $n$, show that for every nonzero $x$ we have to $χ_{A^{-1}}(x)=\frac{x^n}{χ_{A(0)}}χ_{A}(1/x)$, where $χ_{A}(x)$  represents the characteristic polynomial of $A$. I do not know how to start with this exercise, I feel that the theorem of Cayley-Hamilton could help me with the inverse expression of $A^{-1}$ but I really have no idea. Any help will be appreciated- Thanks and best regards.

Comment: what is $n$?${}{}{}{}$

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo The size of the matriz $A$

Comment: are you sure $n$ is not even?

Comment: If we let $A$ be the identity of size $1\times 1$ this literally says $(1-x)=x(1-1/x)=(x-1)$

Comment: @Jorge look at my answer...I ignored the $x$ aspect, so more work may be needed to finish the original problem

Comment: isn't the original problem false?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/511009/characteristic-polynomial-of-an-inverse.

Comment: I can't vote to close @lhf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $\chi_A^{-1}(x)\chi_A(0)=\det(A^{-1}-xI)\det(A)=\det(I-xA)=x^n\det(\frac{1}{x}-A)=(-x)^n\det(A-\frac{1}{x})=(-x)^n\chi_A(\frac{1}{x})$

Comment: But I should not stay at the end $(-x)^n$?

Comment: I think it's false otherwise, consider the case in which $A=I_1$

Comment: It is an exercise in the book and does not specify anything about A, I do not know if it is a mistake of the book, although it does not seem.

Comment: Did you try out my last comment?

Answer (score 1):

Write out the characteristic polynomial as
$$ A^n + c_{n-1} A^{n-1} + c_{n-2} A^{n-2} + \cdots + c_{1} A + c_0 I = 0.  $$
Multiply through by $A^{-n}.$ The result may not be monic, the coefficient of $A^{-n}$ is $c_0.$ So, divide through by $c_0.$ This is now a monic polynomial in $A^{-1.}$

Comment: And that monic polynomial of which you speak is the one that satisfies the equation above?