# Prove conditions on eigenvalues, conditional on coefficients

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, polynomials

I am looking for a relationship between (or conditions on) coefficients 'a' and 'd' in the matrix below that ensures that this matrix has two eigenvalues greater than 1 in absolute value.

I have the following 5*5 matrix :

$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
1.79847+3.74119d & -5.12392 + 4.67648a - 0.935297d & -0.199451 & -0.0666941 - 0.935297d & -0.341908 \\ -0.213141 & 1.03378 & 0 & 0.0236824 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & -0.0221797 & 0 & 0.010101 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0.8d & a-0.2d & 0 & -0.2d & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I would really appreciate if someone could help me arrive at an analytical expression for a relationship between 'a' and 'd' to ensure that two eigenvalues of the above matrix are greater than 1 in absolute value. Thank you very much.

Comment: Please format your matrix correctly; see [this page for details](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). If you are using Mathematica, then you can get the Latex expression for this matrix using the `TeXForm` function.

Comment: Also, you've asked [essentially the same question earlier](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4233593/81360). Please note that reasking questions to get attention is generally frowned upon

Comment: To copy my comment from there: I would recommend that you apply the [Jury](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jury_stability_criterion) or [Bistritz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bistritz_stability_criterion) stability criterion to the characteristic polynomial of the inverse of your matrix. As [the answers here demonstrate](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/511009/81360), if you have the characteristic polynomial $\chi_M$ of $M$, the characteristic polynomial of the inverse is given by 
$$
\chi_{M^{-1}}(\lambda) = (-\lambda^n) \chi_M(1/\lambda).
$$

Comment: Correction: that last equation should be
$$
\chi_{M^{-1}}(\lambda) = (-\lambda)^n \chi_M(1/\lambda).
$$

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "two eigenvalues of the above matrix are greater than 1 in absolute value"? Does that mean exactly two, at most two, or at least two?

Comment: @BenGrossmann- Thanks for your comments! Apologies for the incorrect format as well as for posting the question again. I was told the question wasn't clear, I'll just get rid of the duplicate one. I have corrected the matrix format above. I need to prove that exactly two eigenvalues of the above matrix are greater than 1 in absolute value.

Comment: Interesting. The Jury/Bistritz criterion tells you when you have *no* eigenvalues above $1$ in absolute value, which gives you a sufficient condition for your purposes (but is not exactly what you're looking for)

Comment: @BenGrossmann : Right, thank you! Actually, I am using this for a model in Economics and I have some plausible range of the coefficients 'a' and 'd'. Based on that, I see that the fourth and the fifth eigenvalues of the above matrix (as computed on Mathematica) are bigger than 1. Could that help in any way in arriving at an explicit analytical expression?

Comment: I really don't see how you could make use of the Mathematica expression for the eigenavalues, which simply described the eigenvalues as roots of the characteristic polynomial. Perhaps you could use something like a [root locus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_locus) to investigate things, but I can't imagine that this would lead to an "analytical expression" for your range